# How to get the updated record by comparing two list using linq C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 csv files , one is previous day and one is current day csv file , from previous day csv file i am collecting data in existingDeal list and from current day csv file i am collecting data in dealList ,

after that i want to check the any row is modified or updated based on Id from current day csv file with previous day file .

For ex.
Current day File :

Id : **10**
Name : Bofa
Description : **USA**

Previous day File :

Id : **10**
Name : Bofa
Description : **INDIA**

As shown above Id = 10 is same fro both file but the column Description value is changed , So result will be like below

Id : **10**
Name : Bofa
Description : **USA**

if there is no any result is modified in current day file comparing with previous day file then it will be null or empty .

Code:

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<Deal> dealList = new List<Deal>
            {
                new Deal{ Id = 10, Name = "Bank of America", Description = "Pay Bill"}
            };


            List<ExistingDeal> listExistingDeal = new List<ExistingDeal>
            {
                new ExistingDeal { Id = 10, Name = "Bank of America", Description = "Pay Bill"},
                new ExistingDeal { Id = 11, Name = "Bank of America11", Description = "Pay Bill"},
                new ExistingDeal { Id = 12, Name = "Bank of America12", Description = "Pay Bill"},
                new ExistingDeal { Id = 13, Name = "Bank of America13", Description = "Pay Bill"},
                new ExistingDeal { Id = 14, Name = "Bank of America14", Description = "Pay Bill"}
            };

// this is for getting new records by comparing previous day file with current day file 
            var newRecords = (from drNew in dealList
                              join drOld in listExistingDeal on drNew.Id equals drOld.Id into match
                              where !match.Any()
                              select drNew).ToList();
```

Below code is for getting updated or modified records from current day file by comparing the previous day file - but below code returns modified or updated row but if there is no any modification or updation in current file still it returns the rows which is not correct

```
            var updateRecords = (from drNew in dealList.AsEnumerable()
                                 join drOld in listExistingDeal on drNew.Id.ToString() equals drOld.Id.ToString()
                                 where !Equals(drNew, drOld)
                                 select drNew).ToList();

            //Below code works fin when i use data table 
            //var updateRecords = (from drNew in dt1.AsEnumerable()
            //                     join drOld in dt2.AsEnumerable() on drNew.Field<string>("Id") equals drOld.Field<string>("id")
            //                     where !DataRowComparer.Default.Equals(drNew, drOld)
            //                     select drNew).ToList();
        }

    }

    public class Deal
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    public class ExistingDeal
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: So, what's the issue/question?

Comment: var updateRecords returns the record which is not updated record. if we check both records for Id = 10 the they are same but still var updateRecords are returning record

Comment: is there any option ? how can u achieve this

Answer (score 0):

A few things to think about as you code.  First, why have two classes that have identical data structures?  If Deal and ExistingDeal are structurally the same there is no need.  If ExistingDeal inherits from Deal then you want to structure your classes like `class ExistingDeal: Deal {...}`.

To directly answer your question i would use Linq.  There are some very useful linq extension libraries that might do this for you.  Nevertheless, here is an example.

Notice that i created a method called HashValues in `class Deal`.  `HashValues()` creates a  deterministic guid out of `Name` and `Description` (you could pass more key values as well).  Use a technique like this to selectively compare properties of a class without having to iterate over each property.

```
    [Test]
    public void test_compare_twolistsforchanges()
    {

        List<Deal> newDeals = new List<Deal>()
        {
            new Deal { Id = 10, Name = "Bank of America Deal Has Changed", Description = "Pay Bill"},
            new Deal { Id = 11, Name = "Bank of America11", Description = "Pay Bill"},
            new Deal { Id = 12, Name = "Bank of America12-12", Description = "Pay Bill"},
        };
        List<Deal> oldDeals = new List<Deal>
        {
            new Deal { Id = 10, Name = "Bank of America", Description = "Pay Bill"},
            new Deal { Id = 11, Name = "Bank of America11", Description = "Pay Bill"},
            new Deal { Id = 12, Name = "Bank of America12", Description = "Pay Bill"},
            new Deal { Id = 13, Name = "Bank of America13", Description = "Pay Bill"},
            new Deal { Id = 14, Name = "Bank of America14", Description = "Pay Bill"}
        };

        // Using Linq - get all new deals where the new deal and the old deal share an id 
        // AND the old deal hash doesn't match the new deal hash
        var result = newDeals
           .Where(nd => 
               oldDeals.Where(od => od.Id == nd.Id)
                  .Any(od => od.HashValues() != nd.HashValues())
               );

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Changed => " + result.Count());
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result.Select(x => x.Id)));


    }
    internal class Deal
    {
        private static System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashPRovider = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        internal Deal() { }
        internal int Id { get; set; }
        internal string Name { get; set; }
        internal string Description { get; set; }
        internal Guid HashValues()
        {

            byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(string.Join("", this.Name, this.Description));
            byte[] hashBytes = hashPRovider.ComputeHash(inputBytes);
            Guid hashGuid = new Guid(hashBytes);
            return hashGuid;
        }

    }
```

Comment: for simplicity i have taken same but there are different Properties which i remove at the time of compare  as per your code ( ncoding.Default.GetBytes(string.Join("", this.Name, this.Description)); ) , i am dealing with too many columns which is not good for me to write to many times , can you help me to get using my above code i am searching to do like this thing DataRowComparer.Default.Equals(drNew, drOld) in list

Comment: Equals is not the comparison you want unless you are going to implement the IEquatable<T> interface on your class.  Basically classes which are made of properties and methods need to know how to compare themselves to one another or they only test if they are the same.  I felt that at this point asking you implement interfaces would give you even more challenges then benefits.

Comment: Sorry mistakenly done that , i did'n see that , i have corrected ,  !Equals(drNew, drOld) this was failing some how due to which i am not able to get the modified rows based on ID

Comment: You need to implement the IEquatable interface.  I will update my example.  I hope you can make use of it.